# How to add chrome tab group in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently working on my first chrome extension (MV3) and I wanted to add a new tab group through js. The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-group) say it's possible, but I just can't figure out how to do it. All help is appreciated! :)

Comment: The documentation has been in semi-broken state since the new Chromium developers started to modernize it so I suggest just looking for an existing extension, should be easy to find, then use crxviewer or inspect them in devtools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at a similar chrome extension and managed to figure it out. You do something along the lines of:

```js
aync function test() {
  var groupId = await chrome.tabs.group({ tabIds: tabId });
  chrome.tabGroups.update(groupId, { collapsed: false, title: "title", color: "blue" });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, as I can understand, if you're not passing `groupId`, then it will create one for you, and return it's the id as a result of the promise.